# airflow DAG seems to be missing

Tags: airflow

I have Airflow scheduler and Webserver service running on different instances. When I put the DAG on Scheduler(/usr/local/airflow/dag), I can see the DAG in the web UI . But when I try to click it I get the error

**DAG "tutorial" seems to be missing.**.

If I copy the same file to Webserver, I am done away with the message. So basically I need to copy my dag to both Scheduler and Webserver

I am a newbie trying to configure airflow server with Webserver, Scheduler,2 worker instances. Did I missed something ? How can I share the "DAG" folder with scheduler and Webserver so that they are able to see the same DAG.

Comment: What platform are you running airflow on? i.e. Is it running in AWS, or are you running it via docker on your local machine?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's in AWS. S3 for storing logs, EC2 for Worker, scheduler, webserver. SQS for message queuing.